# TCP Multiple Segment Acknolegdement

Tags: network, tcp, networking, network-theory

Let's take example where in the example i will use the Independent acknowledgment.

Host A has send segment 1,2,3 to the host B, after host b receive each segment it will send a Acknolegdement for each segment so host b will send acknolegdement for segment number 1,2,3. But in the acknowledgment field what sequance number will be filled, whether 4 or maybe 2, 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acknowledgement number is the next expected data. The original TCP definition, *[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)* explains:

> Acknowledgment Number:  32 bits
>
> If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the
> next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to
> receive. Once a connection is established this is always sent.

The latest TCP definition, *[RFC 9293, Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9293)* also explains:

> Acknowledgment Number: 32 bits
>
> If the ACK control bit is set, this field contains the value of the
> next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to
> receive. Once a connection is established, this is always sent.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir